# Display ngForm data via Json Pipe Angular 9 project not showing any data. Converting circular structure to JSON ERROR

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript, pipe

I am trying to display my ngForm data in the HTML file using the Json pipe in my Angular 9 project.

The result I wish to get from the below code should be

```
{"name":"name input","contactNumber":"07123" }
```

I tried this:

```
{{ form.value | json }}
```

and I have also tried

```
{{ form| json }}
```

to display **all** angular ngForm data, but still no luck.

On my HTML nothing is being shown, but if I do `{{form}}`, I get `[object object]`.

Note: FORMS MODULE is imported.

The error I am getting on the console:

```
VM21 vendor.js:15247 ERROR TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'TView'
    |     property 'blueprint' -> object with constructor 'LViewBlueprint'
    --- index 1 closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at JsonPipe.transform (VM21 vendor.js:5866)
    at Module.ɵɵpipeBind1 (VM21 vendor.js:43023)
    at BookingFormComponent_Template (VM20 main.js:579)
    at executeTemplate (VM21 vendor.js:20324)
    at refreshView (VM21 vendor.js:20171)
    at refreshComponent (VM21 vendor.js:21609)
    at refreshChildComponents (VM21 vendor.js:19900)
    at refreshView (VM21 vendor.js:20223)
    at refreshComponent (VM21 vendor.js:21609)
```

HTML code:

```
<form #form="ngForm" class="box p-4 mx-lg-0 mx-1 mb-3 rounded font-weight-bold">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="clientName">Name</label>
<input id="clientName"  placeholder="Enter your name!" ngModel/>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="contactNumber">Contact Number</label>
<input id="contactNumber"  placeholder="Enter your contact number!" ngModel/>
</div>
<h3>{{ form | json }}</h3>
<h3>{{ form.value | json }}</h3>
```

Comment: Please can you mark the answer as correct. He's gone to some effort and I can confirm the answer is correct.

Comment: I imagine you have already figured something out, but {{ form.form | json }}  will return data with no error. I was running into the same issue when working with an Angular tutorial from 2019.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the circular object error I based my answer on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cyclic_object_value#Examples
, you need to add a custom pipe named something like: circular-object-to-json.pipe.ts and add the code:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

    @Pipe({ name: 'circularObjectToJsonPipe' })
    export class CircularObjectToJsonPipe implements PipeTransform {
        transform(circularObj: any): any {

            const getCircularReplacer = () => {
                const seen = new WeakSet();
                return (key, value) => {
                    if (typeof value === "object" && value !== null) {
                        if (seen.has(value)) {
                            return;
                        }
                        seen.add(value);
                    }
                    return value;
                };
            };

            return JSON.stringify(circularObj, getCircularReplacer());
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to add the new pipe to the declarations array in app.module.ts:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        CircularObjectToJsonPipe,
    ],
```

Rewrite your form:

```
<form
    #form="ngForm"
    (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(form.value)"
    class="box p-4 mx-lg-0 mx-1 mb-3 rounded font-weight-bold"
>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="clientName">Name</label>
        <input
            name="clientName"
            ngModel
            placeholder="Enter your name!"
        />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="contactNumber">Contact Number</label>
        <input
            name="contactNumber"
            ngModel
            placeholder="Enter your contact number!"
        />
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

    <pre style="font-size: 1rem; white-space: pre-wrap;">{{ form | circularObjectToJsonPipe }}</pre>

    <h3>{{ form.value | json }}</h3>

</form>
```

And add onSubmit function in your component.ts:

```
onSubmit(formValues) {
    console.log(formValues);
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm why this error has occurred? As having looked at a few tutorials the Json pipe auto converts the ngform instance with no issue.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to do this if using template driven is the following:

Everytime you want to see the values of a NgForm, say called myForm, just create a button and when it is clicked just call console.log(myForm.value)

that's it